# how to get submit a foreign key into a form post? python /django

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-key-relationship

actually I don't have a form, I am currently using the `ViewSet` to create API.

I have two models, one is a regular user model and a group model which uses a field named `creator` with ForeignKey to the user

I created a serializer then use it to validate the `POST` inputs, somehow I keep on getting the error saying

`null value in column "creator_id" violates not-null constraint`

Which I can understand and I tested too that it's because `creator_id` is null when I try to post, but I did enter the `creator_id` though.  Am I entering it in a wrong way or how do I get the foreign key in order to save it?

My group model is like this

```
class Group(Model):
    creator = ForeignKey(User,
                         null=True,  // I used this to test I am right with the error
                         blank=True,  // I used this to test I am right with the error
                         on_delete=CASCADE,
                         related_name="%(class)ss",
                         related_query_name="%(class)s")
    group_name = CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.group_name
```

again, I added `null=True, blank=True` is because I want to see if I am right that it's because of `creator_id` can't be null and yes I am right, after adding these two fields, I don't get the error anymore.

my GroupSerializer

```
class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    group_id = SerializerMethodField()
    creator_name = SerializerMethodField()
    creator_id = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['group_id', 'group_name', 'creator_id', 'creator_name']

    def get_group_id(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    def get_creator_name(self, obj):
        return obj.creator.tutor_name

    def get_creator_id(self, obj):
        return obj.creator.id

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

my view.py

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def create(self, request):
        data = GroupSerializer(data=request.data)  // this would return the `group_name` and `creator_id` I entered
        if data.is_valid():  // this would return true
            data.save()
            return Response({'status': True})
        return Response({'status': False, 'message': data.errors}, status=400)
```

I tried posting using...

```
    {
        "group_name": "bridge",
        "creator_id": 1
    }
```

tried `"creator_id": "1"` and `"creator": "1"`

still getting the same error...

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are declaring your serializer wrong. You are using a ModelSerializer, but the fields you are declaring in the fields list don't match the model's fields. Also note that `fields` is a list, not an array. I think it should be something like this.

```
class Group(Model):
    creator = ForeignKey(User,
                         on_delete=CASCADE,
                         related_name="%(class)ss",
                         related_query_name="%(class)s")
    group_name = CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.group_name

class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('creator', 'group_name', 'created_at')
```

Also I know you were doing it to test, but its considered bad practice to declare both `null=True` and `blank=True` on the same field. It should be one or the other.

See the docs here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Comment: I can understand what you mean, but what if I want to change `creator` into `creator_id` ? this is where I am stuck.  let's say I know the model uses 'group_name` but I am able to change it to `g_name` if I want through the `SerializerMethodField`

Comment: Well in your model, `creator` is a ForeignKey. So in Django it doesn't actually refer to an id number, its a reference to another model (in this case `User`). That model has its own `id` field. If you wanted the `creator_id` it would actually be `creator.id` since that would refer to the `User` models `id` field.

Comment: that's why I have `def get_creator_id(self, obj):return obj.creator.id` which then is inputed into the `fields` of the serializer or then how can I get the id of the creator though?